# Definition of Galois Group

Tags: galois-theory

I'm revising for a module on Galois Theory and have trouble understanding the definition for a Galois group of a field extension $K:F$.

Define the Galois group of $K:F$ as $\Gamma(K:F)=\{\sigma \in \operatorname{Aut}(K)|\forall a\in F, \sigma(a)=a, F\leq \operatorname{Fix}(\sigma)\}$

I can't quite understand the point of that last condition, $F\leq \operatorname{Fix}(\sigma)$.

Also, the next statement after the definition is: Clearly, $F \leq \operatorname{Fix}(\Gamma(K:F))$.

Why is this so?

Comment: From what book is that? It seems to me that $\,\forall\,a\in F\;,\;\sigma a=a\,$ and $\,F\le Fix(\sigma)\,$ are just the same...

Comment: This is the definition given to me by the lecturer of the module. Why are they the same though?

Comment: Because, if we're using the more or less widepsread, standard definitions, then $$Fix(\sigma):=\{t\in K\;;\;\sigma t= t\}\,$$ , so that if for all $\,a\in F\;,\;\;\sigma a=a\,$ ,then clearly $\,F\le Fix(\sigma)\,$ ...

Comment: Oh right. Yeah now that you mentioned it, that's blindingly obvious. So then by what you said, does it suffice for the definition of a Galois group to just have $\Gamma(K:F)=\{\sigma \in Aut(K)|\forall a\in F, \sigma(a)=a\}$?

Comment: Yes indeed, @Haikal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental tool in Galois theory is the Galois connection induced by the binary relation '*fixing*' between automorphisms and elements of a given field.

In other words, write e.g. $\newcommand\f{\,\mathtt f\,} \alpha \f x$ for $\alpha(x)=x$, if $\alpha:K\to K$ automorphism, and $x\in K$.

Now the given notations, by definition.
$$Fix(\sigma)=\{a\in K\,\mid\, \sigma\f a\} $$
So, $F\le Fix(\sigma)$ means exactly that all elements of $F$ are fixed by $\sigma$. Suppose that $K$ is fixed.
$$\Gamma(K:F)=\{\sigma\,\mid\,F\le Fix(\sigma)\}\,.$$
Now the assignments $\Phi:S\mapsto \{\sigma\in Aut(K)\,\mid\, \forall s\in S: \sigma\f s\}$ and $\Psi:H\mapsto \{a\in K\,\mid\,\forall\sigma\in H: \sigma\f a\}$ map any subsets $S\subseteq K$ and $H\subseteq Aut(K)$ to a *subgroup* and a *subfield*, respectively.

Now we have $\Gamma(K:F)=\Phi(F)$ and $Fix(H)=\Psi(H)$, and we want to prove $F\subseteq \Psi(\Phi(F))$, but this is immediate from the definitions, as for an $s\in F$, we have $\sigma\f s$ for all $\sigma\in\Phi(F)$.

In general, try to prove (for arbitrary binary relation $\f$ between aribtrary two sets) that both $\Phi$ and $\Psi$ *reserves the order* given by inclusion, hence both compositions $\Phi\circ\Psi$ and $\Psi\circ\Phi$ are monotonic,
 and that already $\Phi\circ\Psi\circ\Phi=\Phi$ and $\Psi\circ\Phi\circ\Psi=\Psi$.